# Does this nonstandard .war file require modification?

Tags: java, war

I have been asked to update an existing system before it is redeployed. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source for the update - someone else has to get the full package, extract the bit I'll use (a .war file), and then send just that bit to me. My job is to modify the makefile to use the new version, and make any code changes needed to address compatibility issues.

In the last four versions I received the contents of the .war were all standard, but the latest file has everything contained in an extra folder in the root. The difference between the two is like this:

[image: Two directory trees, one of which contains an extra folder between the root and the first branches]

I assumed what I'd been sent was good and I was just messing up the makefile, but I'm starting to wonder if that's not the case. The big thing I'm noticing is that in version 2.1, the paths referenced in the web.xml file don't seem to acknowledge the additional folder. For instance, there's a reference to a config file, but it's pointing at `/WEB-INF/unit4.properties` instead of `/software/WEB-INF/unit4.properties`

Is the file I've received likely fine, or is this something unusual? And if I do need to alter what I received, is there anything I'll need to do when modifying the .war beyond just extracting it to a folder, changing the directory, then zipping it back up and renaming it as a .war file?

Comment: A war file has a specific format; you cannot add arbitrary subdirectories. A JavaEE application server looks in certain places for certain things. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format). The file you have is not a war file.

Comment: In short ... they messed up.  Bounce this back to the people who sent you that "not really a WAR" file.